# pptx python set row height in a table

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx0vl.png)

```
left = Inches(0.2)
top = Inches(1.0)
width = Inches(15.0)
height = Inches(3)
column_width= [Inches(0.2),Inches(0.4),Inches(2),Inches(0.43),Inches(0.43)]
```

I want to create a table, which has the first row(heading)'s height is only Inches(1.0), and other rows# heights are Inches(3). I can only set the rows' heights for all rows, but not customize it.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Each row has a writable `.height` attribute. While you can't set that in the `.add_table()` call, you can do it immediately thereafter or any later time that is convenient.

```
row = table.rows[i]
row.height = Inches(3)
```